# windows store app play and download online mp3s in backgroud

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, mp3

I've multiple online mp3 links generated dynamically

```
    http://blabla/1.mp3
    http://blabla/2.mp3

    .... etc
```

the length of each one from 30 s to 3 min, when the user choose to play some mp3s, they should be played and saved to be available offline, and the play and download should continue if the user navigate away from the app

---

so how to play online mp3's and download them to be available `offline`? i need the download and the playing continue while the application is not active.